# Internet access of an Android application -- but restricted to a single domain

Tags: android, security

I notice that (too) many applications on my Android phone require full internet access. In some cases, it seems like they just want to connect to some service. In other cases, it is clear they are phoning home. However, it seems like users have no easy way of checking which one is the case.

I realize that in the manifest permissions for Android there is a "android.permission.INTERNET", but is there a way to say "this application will only access some.domain.org", and maybe specify which protocols will be used, or something like that? Could the Android system enforce that somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, `android.permission.INTERNET` is the most specific you can get. I agree that it would be nice to be able to specify that my app only talked to an individual server, but in the end it wouldn't tell the user anything meaningful, since most protocols can be tunneled and proxied over most other ones with sufficient ingenuity.

The android UI devs decided to go with the broader permission rather than confusing regular users by displaying information that would not be functionally meaningful. As an alternative, you might consider including a note in either your application description or a popup immediately after installation that explains precisely how and why your application accesses the internet.

**Edit:**

You *might* be able to circumvent that permission altogether if you only wanted one-way messaging to the phone and did something excessively clever with [C2DM](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/android-cloud-to-device-messaging.html). This would be a bad thing to do, however, and I haven't verified that it would actually work without that permission.

Comment: That is too bad. I wished there was a more fine-grained permission infrastructure.